# How do I put a list in if statement in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*
public class text_baes_adventure_game {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>()
        list1.add("Yes")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)
        String name = ""
        String y_N1 = ""
        System.out.println("Hi what is your name: ")
        name = input.nextLine()
        System.out.println("Hi "+name+" whould you like to play a dungeon game?: ")
        y_N1 =  input.nextLine()
        if (y_N1 == list1){
            System.out.println("Ok lets start!")
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Ok bye!")
        }
    }
}
```

1.How do I add a list to the if statement
2.I'm a beginner in java so can someone help me

Comment: what exactly are you trying to check? do you understand why that if statement will never return true?

Comment: Is that your actual Java code? Does it compile? (Hint: it shouldn't or it isn't your actual code)

Comment: Can you explain further what are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to check if the user has entered "Yes", then why not simply check `if ( "Yes" == y_N1)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (y_N1 == list1){
```

This doesn't check whether or not the list contains the String y_N1, it checks whether both objects point to the same Object in memory, which isn't possible.

If you mean to check whether or not the list contains the String, use this:

```
if ( list1.contains(y_N1))
```

instead.